# Cannot assign to read only property 'href' of object in AMP project

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I need to redirect page to some of one URL when post event is complete

I have one task that is I need to call AMP event on button click. But I am getting error that is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'href' of object '[object WorkerLocation]'
  at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (fbd7c59c-7201-4dac-af7d-b737f74a7653:67)"

```
function loadDoc(urladd) {    
    console.log(urladd);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            const response = this.responseText;
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(obj);

            if (obj.updatetopcartsectionhtml) {
                document.getElementById("topcartlink").innerHTML = obj.updatetopcartsectionhtml;
            }
            if (obj.success) {
                console.log("aaaaaaaaa" + obj.success);
            }
            if (obj.redirect) {
                console.log("start");
                //window.location = "HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM";   
                //window.URL.revokeObjectURL("HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM");
                location.href = 'http://www.example.com'; //or
                location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
                location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
                console.log("end");
               //window.location = "http://localhost:15536/build-your-own-computer";
                //const canon = "http://localhost:15536/build-your-own-computer";
                //document.location = canon.href;
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:15536/addproducttocart/catalog/1/1/1", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: try to use window.location  = URL; and also wirte this location redirect code after console.log('end')

Comment: @Rishab window.location = URL; is also not working in AMP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027232/how-to-redirect-a-page-amp 
This will help you out

Comment: thanks but i need redirect page to some of one URL when post event is complete

Comment: Why does that matter? Just use the way described in the linked function, and use it in your `onreadystatechange` callback. I.e. `AMP.navigateTo(...);`

Comment: AMP.navigateTo(...); is not working  show me console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: AMP is not defined"